# Combining the output of "aws iam list-users" and the corresponding information from "aws iam list-groups-for-user"

Tags: shell, aws-cli

How would I pass all of the output from "aws iam list-users" and reference the username so i can pull all of the corresponding information from "aws iam list-groups-for-user"? Preferably into a nice neat .tsv file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To join (in the SQL sense) the tables returned by `aws iam list-users` and iterations of `aws iam list-groups-for-user` as tab-separated data, you could try something like this:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

aws iam list-users --output text > users.txt

cut -f6 users.txt | while read user ; do
  (echo $user ; aws iam list-groups-for-user \
      --user-name $user \
      --output text) | paste - - >> groups.txt
done

join -1 6 -2 1 users.txt groups.txt
```

Notes:

- Specifying `--output text` causes all AWS CLI commands to return tab-separated data. Thus the first line creates a "table" `users.txt` from `aws iam list-users`.
- Note that the cut command uses the tab as its default delimiter. So we read the user from the 6th field and for each user run `aws iam list-groups-for-user`.
- Note the `paste - -` command "pastes" the two preceding lines of text on the same line. The purpose of this is to add the user into a field in the `groups.txt` table so that we then have a field to "join" on.
- The `join -1 6 -2 1 users.txt groups.txt` is like an SQL join on the `users.txt` and `groups.txt` tables. The `-1 6` says use the 6th field from the 1st file and `-2 1` says use the 1st field from the second file as the field to join on.

If you wanted to remove some of those fields in your output you can modify the join command. You do this my specifying a list of fields to include via `-o`. E.g.

```
join -o 1.6,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.6,2.3,2.4,2.5,2.7 -1 6 -2 1  users.txt groups.txt
```

This says select the 6th, 3rd, 4th, 5th fields from the first file and the 6th, 3rd, 4th, 5th and 7th from the second file.

Comment: Thank you Alex, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: Note: you can also use the query feature of the awscli e.g. to get the list of IAM user names: `aws iam list-users --output text --query "Users[].UserName"`. That way you can avoid intermediate files, and reduce the need for third-party tools such as awk, grep, sed, cut etc.

Answer (score 2):

This might get you started:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash

users="$(aws iam list-users \
  --query 'Users[].UserName' \
  --output text
)"
for user in $users ; do
  groups="$(aws iam list-groups-for-user \
      --user-name $user \
      --query 'Groups[].GroupName' \
      --output text \
    | paste -s -d, -  # join newlines as comma-separated values
  )"
  printf "%s\t%s\n" "$user" "$groups"
done
```

Comment: Thanks Alex, I was ideally looking to output all the list-user data as well. I did try and use your script and amend it but its just looking not its playing nice with me.

Comment: I have added a second answer after understanding what you meant. I will leave this answer here because it's potentially useful to others.